# How do I make it so that the width of a div compensates for the content inside of it?

Tags: css

I have a list inside a div with text of varying lengths. How do I make the div's width hold all of that content. I've tried `width: auto` (without actually knowing what would happen), but the div stretched out to the left of the window. Is there a property with which I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: That's exactly what `width: auto` is supposed to do (by the way that's the default, so no need to specify it). If you want to constrain the width, use `max-width`. Is there something else that you want to achieve?

Comment: But that's the thing, I did `width: auto` but the div stretched out all the way. -- Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/H66TB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can use `display: inline-block;`

http://jsfiddle.net/H66TB/1/

I'm taking you to mean that you want it to stretch to the content and not just go all the way to the end of the screen.